# For which vector $y$ does the equation $Ax = y$ have a solution $x$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I have a linear algebra problem given a matrix $A$ which is $5×5$ and the problem asked this question: For which vector $y$ does the equation $Ax = y$ have a solution $x$? ($x$ and $y$ have vector notation) What does this mean? Can somebody let me know? Thank you!

Comment: "*$x$ and $y$ have vector notation*" this means these are not scalars. Specifically, $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^5$.

Answer (score 0):

See here:
[System of linear equations - Consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Consistency)

Your system has a solution if it's consistent.

> According to the Rouché–Capelli theorem, any system of linear equations (overdetermined or otherwise) is inconsistent if the rank of the **augmented matrix** is greater than the rank of the **coefficient matrix**. If, on the other hand, the ranks of these two matrices are equal, the system must have at least one solution. The solution is unique if and only if the rank equals the number of variables.

See also this [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem)
I think in my country it's known as **Kronecker theorem**. 
But now I see that in English it's better to call it **Rouché–Capelli theorem**.

Comment: Here can you tell me what exactly the problem meant when it asked "for which vector y" ?. Like I'm supposed to find some kind of general form of vector y or something like that ? Thank you

Comment: @DonaldGingeright For those vectors $y$ for which the augmented matrix $(A|y)$ has rank which is $=$ the rank of $A$. This is what the theorem says. This is the answer you're supposed to give.

Comment: @DonaldGingeright Note that we always have: $rank((A|y)) \ge rank(A)$ So the system has a solution when the two ranks are equal. If $rank((A|y)) \gt rank(A)$ then the system has no solution i.e. is inconsistent.

Comment: @DonaldGingeright I think you can also reply like this: when the column-vector $y$ is linearly dependent on the column vectors of $A$. This answer is equivalent.

Comment: got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The product $Ax$ can be viewed as a linear combination of the columns of $A$, with coefficients given by the entries of $x$. (It’s a fairly simple but worthwhile exercise to prove this for yourself.) This means that for any $x$ whatsoever, $Ax$ lies in the *column space* of $x$. What’s more, since $x$ is arbitrary, we can come up with an $x$ for any arbitrary linear combination of those columns. Therefore, the equation $Ax=y$ can be solved iff $y$ is an element of $A$’s column space. So, to answer this question, you’re probably meant to described this space in some more explicit way.

Comment: "*lies in the column space of $x$*", you mean the column space of $A$, right?